# Running gulp local on terminal for TypeScript takes forever

Tags: typescript, installation

I was trying my hands on TypeScript and was following the official documentation for installation from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript)

After typing in the command gulp local on the terminal which *Builds the compiler into built/local*, it takes forever with the following line displayed on the terminal-> *Requiring external module ts-node/register*.

I believe that I have TypeScript correctly installed on my machine. I am also using Sublime Text 3 for TypeScript.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

It is broken for me too. It needs to be reported to ts-node / Microsoft

As a workaround the `npm` scripts still point to jake and work fine. e.g. `npm run build` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Gulp is just a Task Runner... It has nothing to directly do with TypeScript. The idea behind Gulp is that you can do stuff like "compress all my javascript files into a single .min.js file"

These tasks are all done in the `gulpfile.js` file and the question is if that is populated with a lot of different commands then it will take awhile... If it is getting stuck and not finishing then the gulp file could have an error in it.

For better help on this question it is helpful to see the gulp file you are running